# Setting not initialized instance variable

Tags: ruby, class, coding-style, instance-variables

Is it elegant to use instance variables in a class which are not initialized and setting them using other methods? Or maybe there is a better way to do that?

```
class Klass
  def initialize(a)
    @a = a
  end

  def set_b(b)
    @b = b
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrast to other languages, If you do not initialize an instance variable it will always be `nil` (whereas in certain other languages you could get something undefined).

As long as other methods of `Klass` do not depend on the instance variable actually having a value, this should be ok.

As for getters and setters, there are `attr_accessor`, `attr_reader` and `attr_writer` (see [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor)).

```
class Klass
  attr_accessor :b
  # there's also attr_reader and attr_writer

  def initialize(a)
    @a = a
  end
end

k = Klass.new :foo
k.b = :bar

k.b
#=> :bar

k.a
#=> undefined method `a' for #<Klass:0x007f842a17c0e0 @a=:foo, @b=:bar> (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it works but Ruby defined `attr_accessor`, `attr_reader` and `attr_writer` for that purpose.

`attr_reader`: create method to read 'a'

`attr_writer`: create method to write 'a'

`attr_accessor`: create methods to read and write 'a'

I think the best way to do that is to use `attr_accessor:a`

```
class Klass
  attr_accessor:a
  def initialize(a)
    @a = a
  end
end
```

Then you can do:

```
k = Klass.new "foo" #example 
k.a = "bar"
```